# How to print this javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following object data:

```
var js_images = {
"newborn_set01_01.jpg":{"filename":"newborn_set01_01.jpg","title":"First Pic","description":"First description..."},
"newborn_set01_02.jpg":{"filename":"newborn_set01_02.jpg","title":"Second Pic","description":"Second description"},
"newborn_set01_03.jpg":{"filename":"newborn_set01_03.jpg","title":"Third Pic","description":"Third description"}
};
```

How would I do something as simple as creating an alert to show the description of `newborn_set01_03.jpg`?

This obviously doesnt work:

```
alert(js_images.newborn_set01_03.jpg.description);
```

Comment: the .jpg part of newborn_set01_03.jpg is probably throwing off the program.... well, actually the "." of the .jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to dot notation, you can access object members using bracket notation:

```
alert(js_images["newborn_set01_03.jpg"].description);
```

Documentation: [MDN - Member Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)